# How is the free particle propagator derived?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, path-integral, propagator

The free particle propagator is a well known function,
for example, see Wikipedia.
However, I cannot find a source that explains how to derive
the free particle propagator.
Please explain how the free particle propagator is derived.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A propagator is the amplitude for a particle to go from $x_a$
at time $t_a$ to $x_b$ at time $t_b$.

Let $K(b,a)$ be the propagator
$$
K(b,a)=\langle x_b|\exp[-iH(t_b-t_a)/\hbar]|x_a\rangle
$$

where $H$ is the free particle Hamiltonian
$$
H=\frac{\hat p^2}{2m}
$$

By the identity
$$
\int|p\rangle\langle p|\,dp=1
$$

we can write
$$
K(b,a)=\int\langle x_b|\exp[-iH(t_b-t_a)/\hbar]|p\rangle\langle p|x_a\rangle\,dp
$$

Replace the momentum operator $\hat p$ with its eigenvalue $p$.
$$
K(b,a)=\int\exp[-ip^2(t_b-t_a)/2m\hbar]\langle x_b|p\rangle\langle p|x_a\rangle\,dp
$$

Recalling that $\langle x|p\rangle=\exp(ipx/\hbar)/\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}$ we can write
$$
K(b,a)=\frac{1}{2\pi\hbar}
\int\exp[-ip^2(t_b-t_a)/2m\hbar+ip(x_b-x_a)/\hbar]\,dp
$$

By the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty
\exp(-ax^2+bx)\,dx=\biggl(\frac{\pi}{a}\biggr)^{1/2}\exp\left(\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)
$$

with
$$
a=i(t_b-t_a)/2m\hbar\quad\text{and}\quad b=i(x_b-x_a)/\hbar
$$

we have
$$
K(b,a)=\frac{1}{2\pi\hbar}
\left(\frac{2\pi m\hbar}{i(t_b-t_a)}\right)^{1/2}
\exp\left(-\frac{m(x_b-x_a)^2}{2i\hbar(t_b-t_a)}\right)
$$

Rewrite as
$$
K(b,a)=
\left(\frac{m}{2\pi i\hbar(t_b-t_a)}\right)^{1/2}
\exp\left(\frac{im(x_b-x_a)^2}{2\hbar(t_b-t_a)}\right)
$$